# Combinatorial optimization with interdependent variables

Tags: java, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

This is my first post on these forums, thanks in advance for all responses.

I am developing a java application in which I have encountered what I believe is termed a “Combinatorial Optimization Problem”. I have only basic math skills, so trying to investigate the setup of such a problem have not been fruitful so far.

Basically, what I would like to do is to program the most efficient way of finding the optimal subset n of a larger set N with variables v1, v2, v3 etc. The variables all have a definite value/score in addition to a value/score that is dependant on certain other variables that may or may not be included in the subset.

I am interested in selecting the subset which gives the maximum total value/score.

So, for example, the full set N consists of the following variables and have the following definite values as well as relations to the other variables:

```
v1  8   { v2 ; v8 }
v2  6   { v1 ; v4 }
v3  9   { }
v4  7   { v2 ; v5 ; v8 }
v5  6   { v4 ; v10 }
v6  8   { v7 }
v7  5   { v6 }
v8  9   { v1 ; v4 }
v9  6   { } 
v10 7   { v5 }
```

Having a relation to one or more other chosen variable means that the total value will have a certain “take-off” – for the sake of this example let’s say one for each relation.
So selecting the first five variables as a subset will give a total value of 30:

```
v1  8   { v2 ; v8 }      = 8 - 1 = 7
v2  6   { v1 ; v4 }      = 6 - 2 = 4
v3  9   { }              = 9 - 0 = 9
v4  7   { v2 ; v5 ; v8 } = 7 - 2 = 5
v5  6   { v4 ; v10 }     = 6 - 1 = 5
```

This is of course not a problem for such small sets, but I am currently facing sets of 100K and subsets of 10K – with the current algorithm, my computer calculated the solution in 3 days!

I do not necessarily need a code for solving this, but rather the optimal mathematical way to do it (if there are any!). Keep in mind though that I’m having a hard time understanding mathematical notation above basic level.

Again, thanks in advance for all responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this problem is NP-hard to find the optimal solution.

If you could solve this problem efficiently then you could solve the NP-hard [maximum independent set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) by setting the value for each vertex to 1, and a very large penalty for each edge.

So you should instead look for approximate solutions.  You may find you get a reasonable answer with simulated annealing or genetic algorithms.

Comment: Took me quite some time, but I have now tried to get a grasp on several of the solutions mentioned here. I eventually ended up with Simulated Annealing. Not sure if it was the correct/optimal solution, but at least it was easy enough to understand and implement - and it seems to perform quite well for what i'm trying to do. Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

To a linear program solver, take an input like

```
v1  8   { v2 ; v8 }
v2  6   { v1 ; v4 }
v3  9   { }
v4  7   { v2 ; v5 ; v8 }
v5  6   { v4 ; v10 }
v6  8   { v7 }
v7  5   { v6 }
v8  9   { v1 ; v4 }
v9  6   { }
v10 7   { v5 }
```

and convert it to a integer program like

```
maximize   8*v1 - v1v2 - v1v8
         + 6*v2 - v2v1 - v2v4
         + 9*v3
         + 7*v4 - v4v2 - v4v5 - v4v8
         + 6*v5 - v5v4 - v5v10
         + 8*v6 - v6v7
         + 5*v7 - v7v6
         + 9*v8 - v8v1 - v8v4
         + 6*v9
         + 7*v10 - v10v5

subject to
v1 + v2 - v1v2 <= 1
v1 + v8 - v1v8 <= 1
v2 + v1 - v2v1 <= 1
v2 + v4 - v2v4 <= 1
v4 + v2 - v4v2 <= 1
v4 + v5 - v4v5 <= 1
v4 + v8 - v4v8 <= 1
v5 + v4 - v5v4 <= 1
v5 + v10 - v5v10 <= 1
v6 + v7 - v6v7 <= 1
v7 + v6 - v7v6 <= 1
v8 + v1 - v8v1 <= 1
v8 + v4 - v8v4 <= 1
v10 + v5 - v10v5 <= 1

binary v1, v1v2, v1v8,
       v2, v2v1, v2v4,
       v3,
       v4, v4v2, v4v5, v4v8,
       v5, v5v4, v5v10,
       v6, v6v7,
       v7, v7v6,
       v8, v8v1, v8v4,
       v9,
       v10, v10v5
```

Your instance size is likely too much for an optimal solution, but one never knows...

Answer (score 0):

You can see your set as a graph. Each vX is a node/vertice with the respective value. Example v1 is a node/vertice with value 8, v2 is a node/vertice with value 6, etc. Then there are edges between them. Example v1 has 2 edges: one for v2 and another for v8. Each edge can also have a value (in your case -1).

So if you use graphs, and select v1 to v5: you have 8 + 6 + 9 + 7 + 6 (vertice value) -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 (edges value).

Try to see this http://jgrapht.org/ to see if it helps you.

Also see some Graph Teory: http://www.people.vcu.edu/~gasmerom/MAT131/graphs.html. Observe Longest/Shortest Path algoritms (example: http://www.maxburstein.com/blog/introduction-to-graph-theory-finding-shortest-path/)